# Shaders and variables in OpenGL 2 on Android / LibGDX

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, libgdx, glsl

Following code is fragment shader which I created using [default LibGDX SpriteBatch shader](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/SpriteBatch.java#L123) simply modified to scramble RGB channels, and it works just fine on both Android and PC:

```
#ifdef GL_ES
#define LOWP lowp
precision mediump float;
#else
#define LOWP
#endif
varying LOWP vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;
uniform sampler2D u_texture;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = v_color * texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoord);
    gl_FragColor.rgb = vec3(gl_FragColor.g, gl_FragColor.r, gl_FragColor.b)
}
```

however when I try to add any variable to shader program like so (i excluded #ifdef ... u_texture; but it's still in shader itself):

```
float test;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = v_color * texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoord);
    test = (gl_FragColor.r + gl_FragColor.g + gl_FragColor.b) / 3.0f;
    gl_FragColor.rgb = vec3(test, test, test);
}
```

it works on pc, but crashes on android - shader compiles fine on android too, but when SpriteBatch ApplyShader method is called app is crashing (according to logcat).

Tried defining variable inline like so:

```
float test = (gl_FragColor.r + gl_FragColor.g + gl_FragColor.b) / 3.0f;
```

But it doesn't change a thing - still works perfectly fine on PC but not on Android. Moreover it crashes even if I write something like:

```
test = 0.4f;
```

Answer (score 1):

GLSL ES differs from traditional GLSL in that it requires precision modifiers e.g.

```
precision highp float;
void main(){
    //....
{
```

your program works fine on your computer because plain ol' GLSL does not require these precision modifiers. Once you jump into GLSL ES however you're crashing because you aren't using them.

Comment: Try not to do that in a fragment shader though. `highp` is optional in fragment shaders (in ES 2.0), there is a pre-processor definition (`GL_FRAGMENT_PRECISION_HIGH`) you should check before setting the default precision to `highp`. And this is really only an issue in fragment shaders in the first place; vertex shaders have a defined default precision whereas fragment shaders do not.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman are you saying not to use `highp` in general? or to avoid using variable in the fragment shader?

Comment: I mean, avoid unconditionally setting the default precision to `highp` in a fragment shader. It is fine if you use it, but you should check to see if `GL_FRAGMENT_PRECISION_HIGH` is defined first. If not, the implementation does not support high precision in fragment shaders. It's optional in GL ES 2.0, but required in 3.0.